# No embedded videos in windows 11

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, youtube

I have a windows 11 laptop that isn't able to play embedded videos, specifically youtube videos in powerpoint.

I did some research and it is this problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-video-from-youtube-or-another-site-8340ec69-4cee-4fe1-ab96-4849154bc6db

I tried all of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/browsers/installation/disable-internet-explorer-windows

And I can launch IE via this method: https://beebom.com/how-enable-and-use-internet-explorer-windows-11/

However, the laptop is still not able to play back videos. The area where the video player would be stays black and unresponsive.

This is on a brand new laptop that has nothing installed other than whatever windows updates were available, office 365 and chrome, the video playback never worked since out of box.

Comment: If the embedded videos require Internet Explorer, they are not likely ever to work in Windows 11.

Comment: Which version of Office (PowerPoint) do you have? Go to File>Account and copy the Version and Build number. I'm on Windows 11 without Internet Explorer at all and embedding YouTube works fine for me.

Comment: IE was permanently disabled in 2023. So the method you used isn’t applicable to the current version of Windows 11 post that Microsoft Edge update.

Comment: it says Version 2304 (Build 16327.20248 Klick-und-Los)

Comment: I am aware that internet explorer is old and discontinued, I am not trying to use it. I just read that it is required for the video playback. If not, then what else can I install to make this work? :/

Comment: You might be missing codecs. I recommend the [K-Lite Codec Pack](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm).

Comment: It works by me with Windows 11 22H2 and PowerPoint 2304 Build 16327.20248 without changing anything on Windows (so no Internet Explorer.)

Comment: Pretty sure it's not required. Perhaps you should add more details such as the method used to embed the video. Also, did you embed it yourself or are you opening someone's files?

Comment: You start by saying that you can't play embedded videos but then say it's basically only in PowerPoint. So to make sure, can you play any embedded video in the Edge browser (try https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo)? And what do you mean by "isn't able to play", how does it look in PowerPoint and what happens when you press the Play button?

Comment: I am embedding it by right click, the embed code is copied from youtube

Comment: thank you  I just saw that the video from the test link does play so it is actually only powerpoint that is affected!

Comment: Right-click and selecting what option from the right-click menu? (You also didn't answer what exactly you do see after embedding.)

Comment: I right click and pick "copy embed code" and then in powerpoint I use the insert function as described by microsoft in the first link that I posted. the video is then just a black box with nothing inside, no player controls, nothing. it is not clickable at all

Comment: I also just installed the K lite and it did not change anything unfortunately

Comment: Can you try resetting your Internet Options settings? (Open the Internet Options from Start/Search --> Go to Security and click Reset all zones... -->Go to Advanced and click on Restore advanced settings --> Press OK to save. Then close PowerPoint and reopen it, and check how embedding videos goes now.

Comment: I restored both internet option settings and did a reboot, it still just has black boxes as the videos. I also sent the powerpoint file to another pc and opened it there, I can see the videos there so it is narrowed down to just powerpoint on this pc

Comment: @HelpIIII - You should start editing your question.  This conversation thread in the comment section is fairly long.